# exception in UIImagePickerView

Tags: objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm getting this error:

[CameraViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e07d0

The code piece is:

```
self.view.alpha = 0.5f;
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
UIImagePickerController *imagepicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
[imagepicker.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
imagepicker.delegate=self;
 imagepicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:imagepicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I've already checked in previous controller if there is a camera available in the device. And this comes up when I'm checking it on a device with a camera.

Should I have something else where there is 'nil' in last line ?

Comment: Is `self` a subclass of `UIViewController`?

Comment: Yes, Its UIViewController

Comment: Are you getting this error under iOs 4.x? `presentViewController:animated:completion:` was added in iOS 5.0.

Comment: Daemn it! Thats it. Thanks rmaddy!

Comment: @trudyscousin Passing `nil` for the completion block is perfectly fine.

Comment: @rmaddy Not to put too fine a point on it, but the docs say `NULL`. In any case, I deleted my erroneous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:` method was added in iOS 5.0. The error indicates you are using an earlier version of iOS. In that case, use `presentModalViewController:animated:` instead. You can use the proper one at runtime as needed:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]) {
    [self presentViewController:imagepicker animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [self presentModalViewController:imagepicker animated:YES];
}
```

There is a similar situation for the methods to dismiss the view controller too.